# hamburgermenu checkbox doesn't get unchecked if i click far away

Tags: jquery, hamburger-menu

to keep it short and simple:
My hamburger menu doesn't close if i click somewhere else.
I tried it in jquery and tried to make it with removeClass and so on, but even with removeClass it didnt work.

```
Here's the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/dtgd551q/
```

And i think to just uncheck the checkbox is the simplest way to do it.

Thanks to everyone who can give me help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e){
 if(e.target.type == "checkbox")
     return;
 else{
    var elem = $('#menuToggle').find('input[type=checkbox]');
    if($(elem).prop('checked')){
      $(elem).trigger('click');
    }
 }   
});
```

```css
body
{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Avenir", sans-serif;
}

a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.1s ease;
}

a:hover
{
  color: black;
}
nav {
 display: inline-block;
}
#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  
  opacity: 0; /* hide this */
  z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
  
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

/*
 * Just a quick hamburger
 */
#menuToggle span
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  
  background: black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

/* 
 * Transform all the slices of hamburger
 * into a crossmark.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: white
}

/*
 * But let's hide the middle one.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

/*
 * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

/*
 * Make this absolute positioned
 * at the top left of the screen
 */
#menu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  
  background: black;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#menu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

/*
 * And let's fade it in from the left
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav role="navigation">
   <div id="menuToggle">
     <input type="checkbox" />
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Info</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="https://erikterwan.com/" target="_blank"><li>Show me more</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You can detect click on any part of the page except the `checkbox` as click on `checkbox` is already working. So, `return` command inside `e.target.type == "checkbox"` confirms that the clicked element is not the checkbox. Now, if it's not checkbox then check if the menu is already opened. If it is opened then `$(elem).trigger('click');` will generate a click on the `checkbox` which will close it.